# How can I get my keyboard to load sooner?

Tags: 12.10, gnome, boot, bios

I'm not sure if I'm wording this correctly, or if it's even possible, but is there any way to make my keyboard available sooner? I can use it once Ubuntu's purple screen comes up, but I can't use it to get into BIOS. Is there a command or a document that controls this?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to change this, though trying a different keyboard may help.  I think wired keyboard usually work better.

Comment: @Seth Sorry I forgot to mention that it is indeed a PS/2. I'm pretty sure the rest of the old keyboards I have lying around are PS/2 also, do you think it's worth trying one of those out?

Comment: I do think it is worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my keyboard works in two ports, but only one of them will give me access to bios. I inadvertently figured this out by having both keyboards plugged in at the same time.  At least that seems to be what happened, either way, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!